# Google Maps API - Keep Draggable Marker Along Polyline in the defined points

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I tried to keep the point of marker in pre-defined points (latitudes/longitudes) which in the array "polypath" in the example, so the marker goes to nearest existed point along polyline, so I can use the selected point to another calculation.

This code below shows the current behavior where user can keep the marker wherever he want in the polyline:

```js
var gmap;
var  currentMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(54.13512, -117.0114),
            draggable: true
        });
var snapToRoute = null;
var polypath = new Array(
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.13512, -117.0114),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.13353, -117.01141),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.1332, -117.01159),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.13241, -117.01157),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.13217, -117.01142),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.12725, -117.01143),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.12185, -117.00125),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.1188, -116.9955),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.11603, -116.99473),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.11517, -116.99281),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.10235, -116.97771),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.10244, -116.96093),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.10197, -116.96067),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.10158, -116.96075),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.09808, -116.95913),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.09725, -116.95668),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.09669, -116.95598),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.08378, -116.9471),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.08218, -116.94696),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.07374, -116.93832),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.07319, -116.93571),
        new google.maps.LatLng(54.07185, -116.93527));
        
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: polypath,
    strokeColor: "red",
    strokeWeight: 2,
    strokeOpacity: 1
   });

function initialize() {
    gmap = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.10244, -116.96093),
        zoom: 12
    });
    
    
     currentMarker.setMap(gmap);
    polyline.setMap(gmap);
   
    
   snapToRoute = new SnapToRoute(gmap, currentMarker, polyline);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function SnapToRoute(map, marker, polyline) {
    this.routePixels_ = [];
    this.normalProj_ = map.getProjection();
    this.map_ = map;
    this.marker_ = marker;
    this.polyline_ = polyline;

    this.init_();
}

SnapToRoute.prototype.init_ = function () {
    this.loadLineData_();
    this.loadMapListener_();
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.updateTargets = function (marker, polyline) {
    this.marker_ = marker || this.marker_;
    this.polyline_ = polyline || this.polyline_;
    this.loadLineData_();
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.loadMapListener_ = function () {
    var me = this;

    google.maps.event.addListener(me.marker_, "dragend", function (evt) {
        me.updateMarkerLocation_(evt.latLng);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(me.marker_, "drag", function (evt) {
        me.updateMarkerLocation_(evt.latLng);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(me.map_, "zoomend", function (evt) {
        me.loadLineData_();
    });
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.loadLineData_ = function () {
    var zoom = this.map_.getZoom();
    this.routePixels_ = [];
    var path = this.polyline_.getPath();
    for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength(); i++) {
        var Px = this.normalProj_.fromLatLngToPoint(path.getAt(i));
        this.routePixels_.push(Px);
    }
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.updateMarkerLocation_ = function (mouseLatLng) {
    var markerLatLng = this.getClosestLatLng(mouseLatLng);
    this.marker_.setPosition(markerLatLng);
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.getClosestLatLng = function (latlng) {
    var r = this.distanceToLines_(latlng);
    return this.normalProj_.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(r.x, r.y));
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.getDistAlongRoute = function (latlng) {
    if (typeof (opt_latlng) === 'undefined') {
        latlng = this.marker_.getLatLng();
    }
    var r = this.distanceToLines_(latlng);
    return this.getDistToLine_(r.i, r.to);
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.distanceToLines_ = function (mouseLatLng) {
    var zoom = this.map_.getZoom();
    var mousePx = this.normalProj_.fromLatLngToPoint(mouseLatLng);
    var routePixels_ = this.routePixels_;
    return this.getClosestPointOnLines_(mousePx, routePixels_);
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.getDistToLine_ = function (line, to) {
    var routeOverlay = this.polyline_;
    var d = 0;
    for (var n = 1; n < line; n++) {
        d += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(routeOverlay.getAt(n - 1), routeOverlay.getAt(n));
    }
    d += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(routeOverlay.getAt(line - 1), routeOverlay.getAt(line)) * to;
    return d;
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.getClosestPointOnLines_ = function (pXy, aXys) {
    var minDist;
    var to;
    var from;
    var x;
    var y;
    var i;
    var dist;

    if (aXys.length > 1) {
        for (var n = 1; n < aXys.length; n++) {
            if (aXys[n].x !== aXys[n - 1].x) {
                var a = (aXys[n].y - aXys[n - 1].y) / (aXys[n].x - aXys[n - 1].x);
                var b = aXys[n].y - a * aXys[n].x;
                dist = Math.abs(a * pXy.x + b - pXy.y) / Math.sqrt(a * a + 1);
            } else {
                dist = Math.abs(pXy.x - aXys[n].x);
            }

            var rl2 = Math.pow(aXys[n].y - aXys[n - 1].y, 2) + Math.pow(aXys[n].x - aXys[n - 1].x, 2);
            var ln2 = Math.pow(aXys[n].y - pXy.y, 2) + Math.pow(aXys[n].x - pXy.x, 2);
            var lnm12 = Math.pow(aXys[n - 1].y - pXy.y, 2) + Math.pow(aXys[n - 1].x - pXy.x, 2);
            var dist2 = Math.pow(dist, 2);
            var calcrl2 = ln2 - dist2 + lnm12 - dist2;
            if (calcrl2 > rl2) {
                dist = Math.sqrt(Math.min(ln2, lnm12));
            }

            if ((minDist == null) || (minDist > dist)) {
                to = Math.sqrt(lnm12 - dist2) / Math.sqrt(rl2);
                from = Math.sqrt(ln2 - dist2) / Math.sqrt(rl2);
                minDist = dist;
                i = n;
            }
        }
        if (to > 1) {
            to = 1;
        }
        if (from > 1) {
            to = 0;
            from = 1;
        }
        var dx = aXys[i - 1].x - aXys[i].x;
        var dy = aXys[i - 1].y - aXys[i].y;

        x = aXys[i - 1].x - (dx * to);
        y = aXys[i - 1].y - (dy * to);
    }
    return {
        'x': x,
            'y': y,
            'i': i,
            'to': to,
            'from': from
    };
};
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the code that interpolates the point to the nearest point on the line between the vertices.

```
var dx = aXys[i - 1].x - aXys[i].x;
var dy = aXys[i - 1].y - aXys[i].y;

x = aXys[i - 1].x - (dx * to);
y = aXys[i - 1].y - (dy * to);
```

change that to return one of the vertices (i is the next vertex, i-1 is the previous vertex):

```
x = aXys[i].x; 
y = aXys[i].y;
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/oqma8tn4/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var gmap;
var currentMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(54.13512, -117.0114),
  draggable: true
});
var snapToRoute = null;
var polypath = new Array(
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.13512, -117.0114),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.13353, -117.01141),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.1332, -117.01159),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.13241, -117.01157),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.13217, -117.01142),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.12725, -117.01143),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.12185, -117.00125),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.1188, -116.9955),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.11603, -116.99473),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.11517, -116.99281),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.10235, -116.97771),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.10244, -116.96093),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.10197, -116.96067),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.10158, -116.96075),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.09808, -116.95913),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.09725, -116.95668),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.09669, -116.95598),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.08378, -116.9471),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.08218, -116.94696),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.07374, -116.93832),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.07319, -116.93571),
  new google.maps.LatLng(54.07185, -116.93527));

var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: polypath,
  strokeColor: "red",
  strokeWeight: 2,
  strokeOpacity: 1
});

function initialize() {
  gmap = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.10244, -116.96093),
      zoom: 12
    });


  currentMarker.setMap(gmap);
  polyline.setMap(gmap);


  snapToRoute = new SnapToRoute(gmap, currentMarker, polyline);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function SnapToRoute(map, marker, polyline) {
  this.routePixels_ = [];
  this.normalProj_ = map.getProjection();
  this.map_ = map;
  this.marker_ = marker;
  this.polyline_ = polyline;

  this.init_();
}

SnapToRoute.prototype.init_ = function() {
  this.loadLineData_();
  this.loadMapListener_();
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.updateTargets = function(marker, polyline) {
  this.marker_ = marker || this.marker_;
  this.polyline_ = polyline || this.polyline_;
  this.loadLineData_();
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.loadMapListener_ = function() {
  var me = this;

  google.maps.event.addListener(me.marker_, "dragend", function(evt) {
    me.updateMarkerLocation_(evt.latLng);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(me.marker_, "drag", function(evt) {
    me.updateMarkerLocation_(evt.latLng);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(me.map_, "zoomend", function(evt) {
    me.loadLineData_();
  });
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.loadLineData_ = function() {
  var zoom = this.map_.getZoom();
  this.routePixels_ = [];
  var path = this.polyline_.getPath();
  for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength(); i++) {
    var Px = this.normalProj_.fromLatLngToPoint(path.getAt(i));
    this.routePixels_.push(Px);
  }
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.updateMarkerLocation_ = function(mouseLatLng) {
  var markerLatLng = this.getClosestLatLng(mouseLatLng);
  this.marker_.setPosition(markerLatLng);
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.getClosestLatLng = function(latlng) {
  var r = this.distanceToLines_(latlng);
  return this.normalProj_.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(r.x, r.y));
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.getDistAlongRoute = function(latlng) {
  if (typeof(opt_latlng) === 'undefined') {
    latlng = this.marker_.getLatLng();
  }
  var r = this.distanceToLines_(latlng);
  return this.getDistToLine_(r.i, r.to);
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.distanceToLines_ = function(mouseLatLng) {
  var zoom = this.map_.getZoom();
  var mousePx = this.normalProj_.fromLatLngToPoint(mouseLatLng);
  var routePixels_ = this.routePixels_;
  return this.getClosestPointOnLines_(mousePx, routePixels_);
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.getDistToLine_ = function(line, to) {
  var routeOverlay = this.polyline_;
  var d = 0;
  for (var n = 1; n < line; n++) {
    d += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(routeOverlay.getAt(n - 1), routeOverlay.getAt(n));
  }
  d += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(routeOverlay.getAt(line - 1), routeOverlay.getAt(line)) * to;
  return d;
};

SnapToRoute.prototype.getClosestPointOnLines_ = function(pXy, aXys) {
  var minDist;
  var to;
  var from;
  var x;
  var y;
  var i;
  var dist;

  if (aXys.length > 1) {
    for (var n = 1; n < aXys.length; n++) {
      if (aXys[n].x !== aXys[n - 1].x) {
        var a = (aXys[n].y - aXys[n - 1].y) / (aXys[n].x - aXys[n - 1].x);
        var b = aXys[n].y - a * aXys[n].x;
        dist = Math.abs(a * pXy.x + b - pXy.y) / Math.sqrt(a * a + 1);
      } else {
        dist = Math.abs(pXy.x - aXys[n].x);
      }

      var rl2 = Math.pow(aXys[n].y - aXys[n - 1].y, 2) + Math.pow(aXys[n].x - aXys[n - 1].x, 2);
      var ln2 = Math.pow(aXys[n].y - pXy.y, 2) + Math.pow(aXys[n].x - pXy.x, 2);
      var lnm12 = Math.pow(aXys[n - 1].y - pXy.y, 2) + Math.pow(aXys[n - 1].x - pXy.x, 2);
      var dist2 = Math.pow(dist, 2);
      var calcrl2 = ln2 - dist2 + lnm12 - dist2;
      if (calcrl2 > rl2) {
        dist = Math.sqrt(Math.min(ln2, lnm12));
      }

      if ((minDist == null) || (minDist > dist)) {
        to = Math.sqrt(lnm12 - dist2) / Math.sqrt(rl2);
        from = Math.sqrt(ln2 - dist2) / Math.sqrt(rl2);
        minDist = dist;
        i = n;
      }
    }
    if (to > 1) {
      to = 1;
    }
    if (from > 1) {
      to = 0;
      from = 1;
    }
    x = aXys[i].x; // aXys[i - 1].x - (dx * to);
    y = aXys[i].y; // aXys[i - 1].y - (dy * to);
  }
  return {
    'x': x,
    'y': y,
    'i': i,
    'to': to,
    'from': from
  };
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry,places&ext=.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```