# Google Maps API Snap Marker To Polyline

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a polyline list (from Google Directions API) that has been drawn on Google Map. Next, I'd like for my marker to move along this line without using Google Maps Roads API.

To tackle this, here's what I'm currently doing:

1. From the polyline list, I'm selecting two end-points of the path A and B.
2. Finding out the bearing from A to B.
3. Creating a list of `LatLng` points between A and B that are 1 meter apart from each other.
4. Iterating through the list to check the GPS coordinates for the nearest `LatLng`.
5. Setting my marker's location to the nearest `LatLng`.

The above works in some cases but mostly the marker displays parallel to the polyline not on it.

Is there any other way to make my marker **snap to the polyline**?

Comment: related question: [Google Maps API - Keep Draggable Marker Along Polyline in the defined points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46285775/google-maps-api-keep-draggable-marker-along-polyline-in-the-defined-points)

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip but this example snaps the marker to the polyline's endpoints. Not to any of the pixels/coordinates in between. If you run the POC provided in the answer, try snapping the marker on A.N.C. Road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my own implementation for snapping marker to polyline (based on GPS location):

First, use the polyline points to create a list of `LatLng` that are at a smaller distance (I'm using a one meter distance specified in `splitPathIntoPoints` function):

```
for (int i = 0; i < polylinePoints.size(); i++) {
    LatLng src = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(polylinePoints.get(i).get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(polylinePoints.get(i).get("lng")));

    if (polylinePoints.size() > i + 1) {
        LatLng dest = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(polylinePoints.get(i + 1).get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(polylinePoints.get(i + 1).get("lng")));
        List<LatLng> splitPoints = splitPathIntoPoints(src, dest);
        mSplitPoints.addAll(splitPoints);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Code for `splitPathIntoPoints`:

```
public static List<LatLng> splitPathIntoPoints(LatLng source, LatLng destination) {
    Float distance = findDistance(source, destination);

    List<LatLng> splitPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    splitPoints.add(source);
    splitPoints.add(destination);

    while (distance > 1) {
        int polypathSize = splitPoints.size();
        List<LatLng> tempPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        tempPoints.addAll(splitPoints);

        int injectionIndex = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < (polypathSize - 1); i++) {
            LatLng a1 = tempPoints.get(i);
            LatLng a2 = tempPoints.get(i + 1);

            splitPoints.add(injectionIndex, findMidPoint(a1, a2));
            injectionIndex += 2;
        }

        distance = findDistance(splitPoints.get(0), splitPoints.get(1));
    }

    return splitPoints;
}
```

Code for `findDistance`:

```
public static Float findDistance(LatLng source, LatLng destination) {
    Location srcLoc = new Location("srcLoc");
    srcLoc.setLatitude(source.latitude);
    srcLoc.setLongitude(source.longitude);

    Location destLoc = new Location("destLoc");
    destLoc.setLatitude(destination.latitude);
    destLoc.setLongitude(destination.longitude);

    return srcLoc.distanceTo(destLoc);
}
```

Code for `findMidPoint`:

```
public static LatLng findMidPoint(LatLng source, LatLng destination) {
    double x1 = toRad(source.latitude);
    double y1 = toRad(source.longitude);

    double x2 = toRad(destination.latitude);
    double y2 = toRad(destination.longitude);

    double Bx = Math.cos(x2) * Math.cos(y2 - y1);
    double By = Math.cos(x2) * Math.sin(y2 - y1);
    double x3 = toDeg(Math.atan2(Math.sin(x1) + Math.sin(x2), Math.sqrt((Math.cos(x1) + Bx) * (Math.cos(x1) + Bx) + By * By)));
    double y3 = y1 + Math.atan2(By, Math.cos(x1) + Bx);
    y3 = toDeg((y3 + 540) % 360 - 180);

    return new LatLng(x3, y3);
}
```

Once `mSplitPoints` is filled with smaller polyline points that are separated by 1 meter apart from each other, the function below finds the snapped location on the polyline based on my current GPS location. Note that `mMinorIndexTravelled` is a private field in my class with initial value set to zero.

```
public static LatLng snapToPolyline(LatLng currentLocation) {
    LatLng snappedLatLng = null;

    Location current = new Location("current");
    current.setLatitude(currentLocation.latitude);
    current.setLongitude(currentLocation.longitude);

    Integer minConfirmCount = 0;
    float currentMinDistance = 0, previousMinDistance = 0;
    List<Float> distances = new ArrayList<>();

    for (LatLng point: mSplitPoints.subList(mMinorIndexTravelled, mSplitPoints.size() - 1)) {
        Location pointLoc = new Location("pointLoc");
        pointLoc.setLatitude(point.latitude);
        pointLoc.setLongitude(point.longitude);

        distances.add(current.distanceTo(pointLoc));
        previousMinDistance = currentMinDistance;
        currentMinDistance = Collections.min(distances);

        if (currentMinDistance == previousMinDistance) {
            minConfirmCount++;
            if (minConfirmCount > 10) {
                mMinorIndexTravelled = distances.indexOf(currentMinDistance) + mMinorIndexTravelled;
                snappedLatLng = mSplitPoints.get(mMinorIndexTravelled);

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return snappedLatLng;
}
```